# Calculating multiple averages using MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been tasked with generating averages for day, week, month, and year for a rather large set of documents in MongoDB.

All of the jobs have a `created` field, and I need to base the average values off of the `outputs` array...

Here's what a document looks like:

```js
{
  __v: 0,
  _id: ObjectId("535837911393fd0200d8e1eb"),
  created: ISODate("2014-04-23T21:58:41.446Z"),
  output: [
    {
      ref: {
        img: false
      },
      type: "image/png",
      methods: [
        {
          options: {
            height: 200,
            width: 200
          },
          method: "resize"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ref: {
        img: false
      },
      type: "image/png",
      methods: [
        {
          options: {
            height: 400,
            width: 400
          },
          method: "resize"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is what my current script looks like:

```js
JobModel.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$output'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $dayOfYear: '$created' },
            day: { $sum: 1 }
        }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        avgDay: { $avg: '$day' }
    }
},
{
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            average: {
                day: '$avgDay'
            }
        }
    }
],
function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    res.send(data);
    next();

});
```

I cannot seem to figure out the right order for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not that sure what you are after here. You say that you want "multiple" averages but that brings up the question of "muliple" over what basis? The average "output" entries over a individual day would be different from the average output entries per month or even per daily average per month. So the scale changes with each selection and is not really a single query for "daily", "monthly" and "yearly"

I would seem that you really was "discrete" totals which would be best approached by first finding the "size" of the output entries and then applying an average per scale:

```js
JobModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$output" },

        // Count the array entries on the record
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "created": { "$first": "$created" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},

        // Now get the average per day
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$created" },
            "avg": { "$avg": "$count" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

Or actually with MongoDB 2.6 and greater you can just use the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator on the array:

```js
JobModel.aggregate(
    [
        // Now get the average per day
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$created" },
            "avg": { "$avg": { "$size": "$output" } }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

So the logical thing is to run each of those within your required [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) range other your aggregation key of either "day", "month" or "year"

You could do something like combining the daily averages per day, with the daily average per month and then daily for year by combining results into arrays, otherwise you would just be throwing items away, which can be alternately done if you "just" wanted the daily average for the year, but as full results:

```js
JobModel.aggregate(
    [
        // Now get the average per day
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "year": { "$year": "$created" },
                "month": { "$month": "$created" },
                "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$created" }
            },
            "dayAvg": { "$avg": { "$size": "$output" } }
        }},

        // Group for month
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "year": "$_id.year",
                "month": "$_id.month"
            },
            "days": { 
                "$push": {
                    "day": "$_id.day",
                    "avg": "$dayAvg"
                }
            },
            "monthAvg": { "$avg": "$dayAvg" }
        }},

        // Group for the year
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.year",
            "daily": { "$avg": "$monthAvg" },
            "months": {
                "$push": {
                    "month": "$_id.month",
                    "daily": "$monthAvg",
                    "days": "$days"
                }
           }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

However you want to apply that, but the main thing missing from your example is finding the "size" or "count" of the original "output" array per document from which to obtain an average.

Comment: Very helpful. I'm trying to get the average values for the lifetime of the user. So it would be the first job ever submitted, to the last job submitted. Any chance you can offer up an example with that? Thanks!

Comment: @NickParsons Not really clear from the context of your question. What is a "user"? I cannot see anything in your methods that point to a "user", per se. I looks like this data is a "child" of a "user" in some way. Without a "user" key on this data your only option is to select the `_id` values of this collection via `$in`. It usually is best that if you have another question then you ask a separate question. It does not confuse the answers given, and it allows you to clearly state your intent.

Comment: @NielLunn Sorry, having a user was confusing. What I am trying to do is generate the average values between a date range. For example, I want to get all of the jobs in the last 30 days using the created time. I then want to get the average jobs for each day, hour, minute, and second. I need to account for days when the there is no document.

Comment: @NickParsons As I already alluded to, I think it is fair to say that your question here is answered. You have been given several pointers as how to approach this and also corrected in the approach you were using. I have also stated that various "timeframes" are not generally possible in a single query unless in the context of the example as has been given. You are changing the context of your question, and though valid as a question it is in fact a different question. You need to post it as such to avoid future confusion for those who reference this question and answer.